# Problems restoring data to a table, ERROR: value too long for type character varying(257)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-rds, database-migration

I'm trying to do a "migration" from Aurora Postgresql to Postgresql on an AWS RDS server. I already have all the infrastructure for the database basically setup and most of the data migrated, but some tables failed to migrate on AWS DMS.

So right now I'm just trying to migrate each table that failed, I made a dump from a specific table using my dbadmin tool DBeaver, it saved it as plain text (.sql) and then I ran it as a script (on DBeaver). I'm getting an error with that specific table and I'm puzzled because I just don't know why it gives me this error when the column data types seem to be exactly the same on both databases, let alone the values.
This is an example of the create table statement on the dump,

```
CREATE TABLE public.indexer(
    id character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    fullnm character varying(255),
    url_display character varying[],
);
```

The value that is giving me trouble is url_display. I've read that this kind of value doesn't have a "lenght limit" and since I didn't specify any sizes like the fullnm column, I'm inclined to believe that there shouldn't be a limit for the string size that can be stored in this column of arrays . However, there are some records that have longer values than 255 characters (say 280) and that's what's causing the next error:

```
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "indexer": ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(257)
CONTEXT:  COPY indexer, line 4159, column url_display: "{https://www.linkedin.com/in/pepememeblabla,http://www.amazon.com/wcderfvsdfg,http://track..."
```

**I'm aware that there are string that are longer than 257 characters, however, that doesn't seem to be a problem on the original database.**

What I've tried:

- I skipped the first record that gave me errors but then other records started triggering this error.
- I haven't tried delimiting a specific size for that column since the original database doesn't have that limit and I wouldn't want to change anything that doesn't need to be changed.
- I'm trying right now to run a dump that was made with the "--inserts" flag instead of "COPY" but I'm pretty sure it will fail too.

I'm a little bit lost and this might be such a simple error that I'm overlooking but I'm kinda lost here right now so any insight would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Shouldn't be a limit other than 10mb from what I can see.   What postgresql version?   What does the insert statement look like exactly?   I see the error says pg_restore, so is it not an insert statement?   Arrays are funny, not used to them, but the error message if funny showing the data without brackets...   It's not trying to insert one string instead of an array, is it?  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v9P9DT6jC5xhS9keSUA5o4/0

Comment: `varchar[n]` is so old fashioned. Postgres supports `text`, which can be any size. Just change the column type and the error should disappear.